# Using writes, wrote or have written

Tags: tense, punctuation

I was reading an article in New Yorker. I found the following sentence:

> In his book “Vladimir Nabokov: The American Years,” the biographer Brian Boyd **writes** that, "as Nabokov ----."

Question #1: Would it be writes/wrote/has written?

Question: #2: Is the comma after *that* appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 It is "writes," since that is what is written. `Writes` is used because it is referring to the text in a book. Even if the author Brian Boyd is dead, we would still use "writes," because the book still speaks, and it speaks in the present tense.

Hemingway (a famous author who is dead) writes in *A Farewell to Arms* "blah blah blah..."

2 We can't really tell if the comma is appropriate, since you didn't provide the complete sentence.

Comment: Thank you @nonplebe for such a nice explanation. It's very clear now. Appreciate for your time.

Comment: Here is the complete sentence: In his book “Vladimir Nabokov: The American Years,” the biographer Brian Boyd writes that, “as Nabokov retold the story decades later, still enchanted by America’s easygoing, good-natured atmosphere, he repeated with delight: ‘Where would that happen? Where would that happen?’ ”

Answer (score 2):

In this case, **writes** seems to be the most appropriate choice, even if **wrote** and **have written** are correct too, but give a stronger sense of past, as if the author does no longer have this opinion.
As for the comma, it is perfectly correct and separates the quotation from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it okay?

In your book "-----," you write that, "the best way to learn is to teach."

Answer (score 0):

The words "has written" are better to my ear than "have written" in the text in the question. In that context "have" suggests either more than one or it suggests a person; it works in the sense "they have ...". By contrast the word "has" suggests just one in phrases like "he has ..." or "she has ..." or "Brian has ...".